# Bundle less with webpack but avoiding compiling it to css

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, less

I want to bundle up my less but avoid compiling it until it's on the client.  This question ([creating a less bundle with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801495/creating-a-less-bundle-with-webpack)) found a solution, but I don't have enough reputation to comment on his answer and ask if he can Opensource the plugin he made.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I flagged that as a non-answer, so either he'll need to post a link to his solution or delete the answer.

Comment: I'm working on a solution at the moment.  I'll post it here when I'm finished.

Comment: @Andrew Have you found a way how to bundle less without compling it? I've got stuck with the same problem.